# Deciding on an edit component that makes fields readonly on runtime

Tags: javascript, if-statement, titanium

I am into making iOS application with Javascript on Titanium. The thing is there are lot of if else conditions currently in my code which make the input fields editable and non-editable based on the status of the document. I want to get rid of this repetitive code hence thought of separating this code into another file and then doing a require. I am assigning a custom attribute on each input element and then passing the Id of the element, the status, and the flag whether it should be readonly to the component. Is this the right approach to be taken? 
**Example: This happens a lot in my code:**

```
function onGetItemsSuccess(result)
  if(result.status == 2){   
    $("#inpPartnerName").attr('readonly',true);     
  }
  if(result.status == 5){   
    $("#inpMfgNo").attr('readonly',false);      
  }
}

function onGetAccountDetailsSuccess(result){
   if(result.status == 1){  
     $("#inpQuantity").attr('readonly',true);       
   }    
}
```

Comment: Try looking into Alloy, it let you start with very nice MVC structure from beginning. Also try posting some example code for better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i did like :
in Utility.js

```
function SetFieldReadability(selector, status){


var itemDetails = {
    modelName : {
        visibility : 'visible',
        readOnly : {
                1 : true, // Approved
                2 : false, // Draft
                3 : false, 
                5 : true    
            },
        isMandatory : false
    },
    description : {
        visibility : 'hidden',
        readOnly : {
                1 : false,
                3 : false,
                5 : true    
            },
        isMandatory : true          
    }
};

var attr = selector.attr('elemName');
    if(itemDetails[attr]){
        var isReadOnly = itemDetails[attr].readOnly[status];
        var isVisible = itemDetails[attr].visibility;
        selector.attr('readonly',isReadOnly);           
        selector.css('visibility',isVisible);
    }           

}
```

And in my working.js

```
 SetFieldReadability($('#inpModelName'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create file let say Helper or Utility file which has only the general validation functions.
e.g.

```
validation.js:

function validate(field,validationtype){
}

working.js:

Ti.include('validation.js');

// here you can access the validate method.
```

That can be the one solution